# Freezing a column in table on jsp creating duplicate value

Tags: jquery, css, jsp

We have a jsp page with multiple tabs where on one tab, we have a table with many columns and we're setting their values with json string. We want to freeze the header and values for first column, however the column value for last row is not freezing, also the column header value is overlapping with first value in column and two duplicate values are shown.

This is the structure we're using:

```
#List').jqGrid(
        {
            datatype : "jsonstring",
            datastr : value,            
            shrinkToFit : false,
            gridview : true,    
            viewrecords : true,
            rowNum : 'auto',
            /* pager : "#pager", */         
            height : 'auto',
            loadComplete : function() {     
                 var data = $("#List").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'data');
                 if(data.length > 0){
                    $("<div style='margin-top:5px;'> </div>").insertAfter($(this).parent());
                 } else{
                    $("<div class='alert-info-grid' style='text-align:center;margin-bottom:5px;'> No Records Found</div>").insertAfter($(this).parent());
                 }
            },
            colNames : [ "S1", "F1",
                    "L", "B", "Ni", "Mi", "A", "S", "",
                    "K", "C", "S", "T", "V", "C", "M",
                    "F", "C", "N", "C", "Z", "G", "R",
                    "S", "Z", "N", "M", "R", "A", "S",
                    "C", "L", "C", "N", "H", "T", "W",
                    "P", "P", "B", "T", "U" ],
            colModel : [ {
               label : "S1",
                name : "s1",
                width : 100
               frozen : true
            }, {
                name : "f1",
                width : 160
            }, {
                name : "L",
                width : 60
            }, {
                name : "B",
                width : 60
            }, {
                name : "N",
                width : 60
            }, {
                name : "M",
                width : 60
            }, {
                name : "A",
                width : 60
            }, {
                name : "S",
                width : 60
            }, .....
            ......
            }, {
                name : "T",
                width : 60
            }, {
                name : "U",
                width : 60
            }

            ]

        });

$("#List").jqGrid("setFrozenColumns");
$("#List").jqGrid('setGridWidth', 1280);
$("#List").parents('div.ui-jqgrid-bdiv').css("max-height", "300px");
$('.ui-jqgrid tr.ui-row-ltr td').css('text-align', 'center');

The values are set as
<Div>
                                    <fieldset id="Listfieldset">
                                        <legend> CP</legend>
                                        <div style="padding-bottom: 6px;">
                                            <form:input path="Unit" value=""
                                                readOnly="readonly" style="width: 80px;" />
                                            <label>Units</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div>
                                            ***<table id="List"></table>***
                                        </div>
                                        <div id="pager"></div>
                                    </fieldset>
                                </Div>
```

Note:The column name differs from the actual used ones.

I've tried with removing label for frozen column as well but issue still persists please let us know if someone can help with this

Comment: Which version of jqGrid is used? Just to note that setFrozenColumns should be the last command when using other methods - i.e set this command as last in your command sequence.

Comment: I think it's 4.5.3, also I tried adding setfrozencolumns to last but no success